# Run commands after restart to default operating system

Tags: sccm

I have SCCM 2012 SP1 and am trying to modify a task sequence to run a couple of command line steps after restarting into the default os to modify a registry setting and a netsh command also.

The problem I have is that after the restart step the OS boots and nothing else happens. Running my steps before this reboot shows in the log that they are successful but the changes are not evident I assume because its operating on the PE environment.

Does anyone have any idea how this is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restart computer task sequence step will only continue the task sequence if you boot back into the boot media, says their [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b116f87-a1df-4194-ad57-f01d797b7d13#BKMK_ResartComputer). However, after the Setup Windows and ConfigMgr step, the machine will reboot, and you can use this reboot to install packages and also run command line steps. For an example, see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/483730/deploying-windows-via-sccm-2012-osd-wireless/517248#517248)